# Showing that $||\hat{f}||_{\infty} \leq ||f||_1$ in $L^1$

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

> Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then
>
> $\hat{f} \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $||\hat{f}||_{\infty} \leq ||f||_1$

How do you prove this or where can I find a proof of this fact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is about the first thing proved in any text on the Fourier transform:
$$
|\hat f(\xi)|=\Bigl|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{ix\xi}\,f(x)\,dx\Bigr|\le\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(x)|\,dx=\|f\|_1.
$$

Comment: Is this $\mu$ a.e?

Comment: Well, yes, but it is everywhere. About the second thing on learns is that $\hat f$ is continuous if $f\in L^1$.